# The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class error while fitting svm

Tags: python, svm

tried to fit train features and labels when using svm, but says i only have the one class label

below is my code:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from art.estimators.classification import SklearnClassifier

dataset=dataset.to_numpy()

features = dataset[:,:-1]
labels = dataset[:,-1]


#label enc
encode = LabelEncoder()
enclabels = encode.fit_transform(labels)

#split data
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, enclabels, test_size=0.2)
train_labels = train_labels.reshape(-1,1)

# train model
model = SVC(C=1.0, kernel="rbf")

classifier = SklearnClassifier(model=model)

#  Train  classifier
classifier.fit(train_features, train_labels)
```

i used the code
`print(np.unique(train_labels))` and it returned:

[0 1]

Comment: can you share the data you are using? How are you defining `SklearnClassifier` ?

Comment: dataset im using is one of the csv files from the cicids2017 dataset